# Android Kotlin coroutines not working as I expected

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I open my app, launch Activity crashes on some devices and it immediately disappears on my device.
Here is my code for launchActivity:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
                preferences[DataStoreManager.NOT_FIRST_LUNCH] ?: false
            }.collect { notFirstLaunch ->
                if (!notFirstLaunch) {
                    editBoolean(DataStoreManager.NOT_FIRST_LUNCH, true)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        activityFullscreenCompat()
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lunch)
                        prepareIntro()
                        lunch_btn_skip.setOnClickListener { //todo gotoSplash()
                            gotoMain()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
                            preferences[DataStoreManager.IS_NIGHT] ?: false
                        }.collect { isNight ->
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                if (isNight)
                                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                                else
                                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                                //todo gotoSplash()
                                gotoMain()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error log

Comment: After the app crashes, error description should appear in Logcat window, please paste it here.

Comment: By the way, you don’t need to do all that dispatcher switching. You aren’t calling any blocking code. No need to mention any dispatchers at all in this code. Then it will use the default of Main for everything so it will be safe.

Comment: are you sure about that? i'm using Jetpack DataStore ! you are saying it's better to remove this codes?  `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {  `  ? @tenfour04

Comment: as i said " it immediately disappears on my device" and does not have crash but someone said to me that it crash for first time i open app(like launchActivity's logic) @RickyMo

Comment: Yes, I’m sure. There is no reason to specify a dispatcher to call a suspend function from DataStore or Room or Retrofit, etc because they all follow the proper convention of not blocking in a suspend function. You only need to specify Main for the whole coroutine since you might be working with functions that must only be called on the main thread. Really you should be using lifecycleScope or viewModelScope.

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend @Tenfour04

Comment: I've not access to their devices and didn't config crashlytics for now(but i will config) whats wrong with this code. I guessed it emit boolean for two times first is ok and it set later and emit that immediatly and skip launchActivity.@DzikiArbuz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little time spending on it i undrestand that when im changing the boolean in:

`editBoolean(DataStoreManager.NOT_FIRST_LUNCH`
DataStore change it immediatly and flow emits new value and before user hit the skip condition runs again and this time with new value and wrong condition becomes true(logicaly) .

Instead i add it on click listener